# Protocol problems: LDAP and GSSAPI authentication

Tags: ldap, openldap, gssapi, der

I'm currently trying to implement GSSAPI support in a third-party LDAP library (the Common Lisp library trivial-ldap). I got it to work when authenticating to an AD server (using the mechanism `GSS-SPNEGO`) but when trying to talk to an OpenLDAP server I get an error reply from the server saying that the mechanism is not supported.

It turns out that OpenLDSP doesn't support `GSS-SPNEGO`, but instead wants `GSSAPI`. The protocol used to do GSSAPI authentication seems very different from GSS-SPNEGO, but my problem is that I can't figure out is what way.

Is there anyone that could assist in explaining how the GSS packets are supposed to be wrapped inside the SASL messages when using the mechanism `GSSAPI`?

I tried simply sending packets in the same form as `GSS-SPNEGO`, but when I do so the SASL handshake never ends. After the context has been created, I keep getting result code 14 (LDAP_SASL_BIND_IN_PROGRESS) as a response to anything I send.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely use the `GSSAPI` SASL mech. This is plain Kerberos 5. `GSS-SPNEGO` is just SPNEGO which will try Kerberos 5 first and if this fails it may resort to NTLM. Active Direcory supports `DIGEST-MD5`, and the two mentioned mechs. I've been using `GSSAPI` mech for years from Windows and Unix.